# Swap a Web App using xPlat CLI in ARM mode

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-xplat-cli

I know how to swap a slot using xPlat CLI in *asm* mode:

```
azure site swap 'sitename' 'slotname'
```

However, how can I swap a slot using xPlat CLI in **ARM** mode?

**Note**: Im *not* looking for Azure CLI 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use `azure webapp config set --slot`

You could get more help by using `azure webapp config set --slot -h`.

```
root@shui:~# azure webapp config set --slot -h
help:    Set webapp configuration
example:  webapp config set RGName WebAppName --alwayson true --numberofworkers 1
help:    
help:    Usage: webapp config set [options] <resource-group> <name>
help:      --slot <slot>                                                the name of the slot
```